# Como fazer o python só ler o arquivo quando o mesmo estiver completo

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, fortran, animate

Eu estou fazendo um programa que lê um arquivo .txt que se atualiza na execução de outro programa em fortran e cria uma animação em tempo real do mapa de temperatura de uma placa, contudo ele está dando um erro devido ao fortran ficar atualizando o arquivo em tempo real, pois em alguns momentos o python abre o arquivo antes do loop do fortran acabar e pega uma matriz incompleta que portanto irá travar o programa. Alguma ideia de como fazer os dois rodarem juntos?

Segue o código em questão a seguir

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import time

n=100
x = np.linspace(0, 99, num=100)
y = np.linspace(0, 99, num=100)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

def animate(i):
        Temp_matrix=np.empty(shape=[0,n])
        file = open('Temperature.txt', 'r')
        for i in range (1,n+1):
                line = file.readline().strip().split()
                line=np.float32(line)
                Temp_matrix=np.append(Temp_matrix,[line],axis=0)
        fig.clear()
        CS = plt.contourf(X,Y,Temp_matrix,9)
        colorb=plt.colorbar(CS)

        plt.title('Placa 1x1')

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Para simplificar, o seu erro aparentemente está em `Temp_matrix=np.append(Temp_matrix,[line],axis=0)`  (...)   `all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly`

Comment: Mas eu nao entendo porque está dando errado, o arquivo que esta sendo atualizado sempre tem dimensões 100x100

Comment: Infelizmente não a posso ajudar. Mas experimente linha a linha e faça também impressão para verificar se está tudo correto.

Comment: Obrigada, eu consegui entender o motivo do erro, se você puder ver as edições que eu fiz e ver se tem alguma proposta eu agradeceria. Mas de qualquer jeito obrigada pela ajuda até agora!

Comment: O que parece é que sua lista carregada em `line` tem uma quantidade de elementos diferente de `n`. Primeiro acho que você precisa checar com algo como `if len(line) != n: print line` para ver se está truncado mesmo por conta da sincronia de leitura/gravação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problema:

O tempo de cálculo costuma ser maior que o tempo de gravação, então considerando um arquivo pequeno (100x100), suponho que esteja calculando com o arquivo aberto:

1. Abre o arquivo para leitura
2. Computa valor
3. Grava valor
4. Fecha arquivo

Nesse processo, é provável que o Python não consiga abrir o arquivo... Ou que leia o arquivo pela metade, antes do término do cálculo.

Há duas formas de evitar isso:

### Abordagem Python:

Use o [Popen Constructor](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) para abrir o arquivo.
Ele retorna um objeto com método [wait()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) que vai ficar esperando até o Fortran fechar o arquivo.

### Abordagem Fortran:

Sugiro rever o código do próprio Fortran.

Você dever armazenar os valores na memória e dar *Flush* apenas quando estiver concluído.

```
call flush(valores)
```

Espero ter ajudado!

:)